# Convert Uint to boolean array / convert uint to binary

Tags: solidity

I would like to convert a uint number to its binary representation, but have so far failed. What would be the best way to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you men by failed so far? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
contract Test {
    uint256 public integer = 100;
    uint256[] public array;

    function fill_array() {
        while (integer > 0) {
            uint256 bit = integer%2;
            uint256 quotient = integer/2;
            array.push(bit);
            integer = quotient;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to have an array of bools, you can do the following.

```
contract Test {
    uint256 public integer = 100;
    bool[] public array;

    function fill_array() {
        while (integer > 0) {
            bool bit = (integer%2) != 0;
            uint256 quotient = integer/2;
            array.push(bit);
            integer = quotient;
        }
    }
}
```

Although I would advise you to try to avoid to do such tasks because it's costly, especially as your integer gets bigger.